# dispatch_async call using UITextView

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get data from an external source using dispatch_async and it works in updating UILabels but nothing else.

Whats the difference in this scenario between an UILabel and an UITextView

Here's the relevante code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
        /* Download stuff */
        PAPavillionInfoModel *info = [PADataSource getPavillionInfo];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            /* Send UI updates back to the main thread. */
            capacity.text = info.capacity;
            inauguration.text = info.inauguration;
            architect.text = info.architect;
            inspiration.text = info.inspiration;

            // THESE NEXT TWO LINES GIVE AN ERROR [message sent to deallocated instance]
            description.text = info.description;
            imageView.image = info.photo;

        });
    });
```

The getPavillionInfo goes to and PHP page and retrieves json data and parses it.

The first lines in the block to the ui thread work. They update the text in UILables, the last two dont.

I'm missing something here but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing syntactically wrong, so I'm guessing the issue is in the return value from [PADataSource getPavillionInfo]. description or photo have been released.

What does this show you?

```
   NSLog(@"info.description: %@",info.description);
   NSLog(@"info.photo: %@",info.photo);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was totally focusing on the wrong side of the problem. The info class's properties had copy instead of retain. The weird part is that the other properties where the same but they worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the async calls, according to the error message. It states that `description` and `imageView` or `info` are deallocated at the time of the call. Check your retain/releases.

Another possibility would be that you somehow deallocate the `info` object in the middle of the run. This could happen e.g. if your `getPavillionInfo` method deallocates the old `info` object for whatever reason.